# how to load images from a tar.gz file in python (using pycharm)?

Tags: python, image, dataset, zip, large-files

I am new to working with large datasets, so sorry if it is a simple question:
I am working on a project where I would like to extract only specific images from the VGGFACE2 (http://zeus.robots.ox.ac.uk/vgg_face2/) dataset, my code receives as an input a file with images, iterate on all the images and move the desired images to a "wanted" (local) folder.
I am trying to run the code on the large tar.gz file but cannot find a way to do so. I tried to unzip it first and got to the .tar but couldn't open this folder and access the images.

working with PyCharm,
python 3.7

thank you

Comment: Did you try the tarfile library (part of standard python) ? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tarfile.html

Comment: yes, I did, I could extract the .tar file from .gz but now I have still a .tar file which I cannot access the images inside it, and couldn't find a function in the documentation that can help.

Comment: Can you show the code used to extract the tar file ? In particular, did you get a TarFile object ? if so, I guess using the extractall method on that object would work.

Comment: If you are working with a compressed tarball, there's no efficient way to extract one file only. Tarballs are not indexed and extracting any one file requires going over the whole archive and effectively extracting all files.